# I want to add milk powder in my bread recipe - what ingredients below do I reduce and by how much?

Tags: bread, milk, flour, recipe-scaling

I would like to add milk powder in my bread recipe to soften the loaf and enhance the flavors. In my ingredient list, I have water, milk, bread flour, salt, sugar, yeast, butter. By what proportions do I have to reduce the other ingredients to add milk powder (around 15grams) into this bread recipe?

Comment: It would help if you posted the amounts in your recipe.

Answer (score 4):

None, will be a perfectly fine "adjustment" to the other ingredients - just toss in the milk powder and leave everything else the same.